# Process Builder: deleting a scheduled action disables the Activate button

Tags: process-builder, scheduled-action

I have an existing process builder (PB) with scheduled actions that is working fine.  I need to make some changes, so I clone the PB and start making changes without activating it.

When I delete a scheduled action, the Activate button is disabled and I can't get it back.  I've tried different things to fix:

- Clone the changed PB to a new version
- Clone the original PB to a new process, then make changes in the clone.

Nothing works to re-enable the Activate button in the changed clone.  This happens in sandbox and production.

Has anyone run into this before?  I've opened a case with SF but hoping to get a quicker answer here.

Comment: Are there any (other) scheduled actions which has schedule defined but no actions defined? If yes, then the `Activate` button in the process builder will be disabled (*this seems to be how process builder UI is designed and I don't see any problem with this since there should any scheduled action without any actions defined*). If your goal is to remove the schedule actions completely, then delete the schedule as well as actions in it. This will enable the `Activate` button.

Comment: @arut That was it, thanks.  If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, the `Activate` button in the process builder UI will be ***disabled***, if there are any `SCHEDULED ACTIONS` with schedule defined and no actions defined (see screenshot below for ref).

[image]

To ***re-enable*** the `Activate` button, add any action or delete the defined schedule in the
`SCHEDULED ACTIONS`.